# How to prevent internal MOSFET from being precgharged?

Tags: mosfet, cmos, comparator, charge

For MOSFET circuits:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ0cFy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Say, how do we make sure that the gates M3, M4 are never pre-charged, so that they will always produce the right result at boot-up?

Though I realize this is a poor example as this one will still settle quickly to produce proper results.

Comment: Did you get this from alien spacecraft?

Comment: What is the circuit meant to do and what does "precharged" mean in the context of the question?

Comment: Also, I think it might be a good idea if you considered marking the best answer to your previous questions as "accepted". This is the very small price that has to be paid when asking questions. People are more likely to help too if you "play the game".

Comment: It appears this is a waveshaper. Seems to be shaping 3.3v regulated voltage with a sine wave generator and a 9v battery. Synthesizer perhaps? Distortion?

Comment: @RichardSmith: I don't think so. Whenever V_in1 goes above V_in2 + Vth(M2), M2 will switch on, driving V_out2 low and V_out1 high (3.3V). Whenever V_in1 goes below V_in2 - Vth(M1), M1 will switch on, driving V_out1 low and V_out2 high. The only ambiguous state is when V_in1 is between those two thresholds, during which time, either all of M3-M6 are off, or they are remembering the previous state. I guess that "the right result at boot-up" is the all-off state. One interesting effect that can be produced is to vary the duty cycle of the output by varying V_in2.

Comment: @Andyaka: Usually I just forget to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind adding a little control logic for the start-up sequence, you could do something like this:
[image: Guaranteed low at startup]

With no voltage applied to the gate of the P-channel JFET, it is a relatively low resistance. Once your circuit has biased, pull the JFET gate high to make it a high resistance. The value of the resistor to the MOSFET (if any) I will leave to you.

I use this technique to guarantee output states during start-up in some places (where the state of signal matters at all times, but during start-up we cannot know the actual state of the signal).

This is *one* possible solution.